# mysql query for a situation?

Tags: join, pymssql

I have two tables,

---

OrderTable(orderid,ordersum)

---

and  OrderPayments(orderid,paidamount).

---

OrderTable

---

orderid      ordersum

---

ORD123456    40,000.00

---

ORD789987    30,000.00

---

OrderPayments

---

orderid     paidamount

---

ORD123456   10,000.00

---

ORD123456   20,000.00

---

ORD123456   10,000.00

---

ORD789987   28,000.00

---

---

---

For an order , payment can be made in installments.

---

I have to get the output as

---

orderid    ordersum   paidamount

---

ORD123456  40,000.00   40,000.00

---

ORD789987  30,000.00   28,000.00

---

I have done using view.

create view op1 as
select orderid,sum(paidamount) as "pamount" from orderpayments group by orderid;

then i used inner join query b/w   ordertable and the view (op1).

I want it to be done in a single query, not to use view / any other table.. Is that possible ? suggest me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner query. 
This is example for join statement

```
select * from OrderTable
inner join (
    select 
        orderid, sum(paidamount) as "pamount" 
    from orderpayments 
    group by orderid
) as tmp using (orderid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. It Works.    But i didnt understand query control flow, can you explain me in detail ?

Comment: what exactly do not you understand? The query works exactly as you would with a view, but instead view using nested query

Comment: Your query was fine, i got the output .  My question is you didn't use on condition, still it is working. how query executed step by step..    By idea is next if i get requirement i should write like you.

Comment: Well written from the inside out. First make the internal requests (like you create views). Then use those queries as tables, just as use and view. In `MySQL` syntax is slightly cramped. So, perhaps, that you easier to understand with `with` statement http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f924/12

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. i got it..   First i tried like  in MSSQL CTE, but filed...  Later, by ur example i got it.. Thanks.